# LaTeX strange new environment definition

Tags: beamer, environments

I'm creating a Beamer presentation and I wanted to change margin size for single slides.  I've found a solution on some old mailing list, adapted it a little and it works perfectly, but I have no idea how it works=/

```
\newenvironment{codemargin}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{-0.7cm}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{-0.7cm}%
      }%
  \item[]}{
  \end{list}
}
```

This creates a new environment that I can use on slides that I want to have smaller margins.

Now to the point - what does \item[]}{ mean?  I can't find any other examples using similar syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rough idea is that the `list` environment (for reasons I don't fully understand) makes various kinds of formatting easier, such as the `setlengths` you have.  I believe it also suppresses the initial paragraph indentation, too.  However, just as with the `itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description` environments—which are all wrappers around `list`—the only permitted text must follow an `\item`.  And since `\item` can take an optional argument (something used to great effect in description lists), an empty one is provided so that you can write

```
\begin{codemargin}
  [This text] demonstrates...
\end{codemargin}
```

Otherwise, the `[This text]` would get swallowed up by the `\item` command.

Comment: I do wonder, though, why the macro writer didn't use `trivlist` instead.

Answer (score 3):

to answer the other part of your question, it seems you are being confused by the order of braces, read rather:

```
\newenvironment{codemargin}
{% begin
     \begin{list}{
}{% do
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{-0.7cm}\setlength{\rightmargin}{-0.7cm}}%
     \item[]
}{% end
     \end{list}
}
```